# Exported class with non-exported data member

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, visibility

I desire to have a shared library `foo` exporting a class `Foo`. As an implementation detail, let's suppose that `Foo` has a private data member of class `Detail` which I do not want to expose.

**Question 1:** Is it okay to export a class with a private data member of non-exported type?

(My understanding: Yes)

---

I'm compiling the following code with `g++ -c -fPIC -o foo.o foo.cpp`:

```
/* foo.h */

#pragma once
#define FOO_API   __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define FOO_LOCAL __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))

class FOO_LOCAL Detail {

};

class Foo {
    Detail d_;
};

/* foo.cpp */

#include "foo.h"

// nothing
```

Under gcc 4.6.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, I get the following warning:

```
foo.h:8:7: warning: ‘Foo’ declared with greater visibility than the type of its field ‘Foo::d_’ [-Wattributes]
 class Foo {
   ^
```

**Question 2:** Why the warning?

I do understand that `Foo` has greater visibility than the type of its data member `Foo::d_`: this is intentional. But why the warning? Is it gcc being overzealous, or a real potential issue with my code?

---

If I change the declaration of `Foo` to:

```
class FOO_API Foo {
    Detail d_;
};
```

Then the warning goes away, but nothing changes: `Foo` still has greater visibility than `Foo::d_`.

**Question 3:** If there is a warning without `FOO_API`, why wouldn't there be a warning with `FOO_API`?

<sub>(Note: I know it is also an option to compile with `-fvisibility=hidden`. I don't get any warnings when doing so. But in this question, I assume we compile without `-fvisibility=hidden`)</sub>